# Angular Ngfor , trigger click on nth(x) item

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor

How can i trigger click on specific nth-child(x) item in ngFor listing ?

```
<ul>
    <li class="list"  *ngFor="let ver of versions; (click)="versionView()">{{ver.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Do you need to trigger the click programmatically **after** rendering the block? Besides, there is a syntax error in your HTML above.

Comment: Yes, I need to trigger the click programmatically after rendering the block @briosheje

Comment: Ok, answer incoming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to trigger programmatically the click on init (assuming you need a **real click event that will also include the propagation**, otherwise you can just raise the click event), you can do that using `ViewChildren` and `NgAfterViewInit`.

Basically, you can use a selector to acquire all the `<li>` items:

```
<ul>
  <li #items class="list" *ngFor="let ver of versions;" (click)="versionView(ver)">{{ver.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

(note the #items selector).

In your component, you can declare a selector targeting "items": `@ViewChildren('items') liItems: QueryList<ElementRef>`.

After that, you can loop through the items after the view is ready and trigger the click on the native html element:

```
  public ngAfterViewInit() {
    const targetItem = 10;
    // If the item is the 10th element, click it.
    this.liItems.forEach((item, index) => {
      if (index === (targetItem - 1)) (item.nativeElement as HTMLElement).click();
    });
  }
```

Full component code sample:

```
import { Component, ViewChildren, QueryList, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  @ViewChildren('items') liItems: QueryList<ElementRef>

  public versions: { name: string }[];

  public constructor() {
    this.versions = Array.from({length: 10}).map((_, i) => {
      return { name: i.toString() };
    });
  }

  public versionView(i: {name: string}) {
    console.log('clicked item: ', i);
  }

  public ngAfterViewInit() {
    const targetItem = 10;
    // If the item is the 10th element, click it.
    this.liItems.forEach((item, index) => {
      if (index === (targetItem - 1)) (item.nativeElement as HTMLElement).click();
    });
  }
}
```

Working stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1eha8j

(check the console to see that the item 10 is clicked)

Beware: In the sample above I've used forEach to loop the items, but you can simply acquire the item you need using `.find` or by simply getting the item at a specific index. The above example is just to show that many manipulations are possible through selectors.

Comment: How can I target a specific item using the index ? any example code?

Comment: @ShibinRagh What do you mean by "a specific item"?

Comment: Yes, I got the syntax (this.liItems.find( (item , index) => index === 1 ).nativeElement as HTMLElement).click();

Comment: @ShibinRagh if you somehow just need to trigger the element at index `3` (assuming you are talking about the array index), you can do `(this.liItems[3].nativeElement as HTMLElement).click()`, you don't need to iterate through it, you can also directly access the array or just use `.find`.

Comment: Its error -  ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

Comment: @ShibinRagh it's likely because the index is out of range, or `liItems` can't be accessed through indexing. Try `(this.liItems.find((i, index) => index === yourIndex).nativeElement as HTMLElement).click();`. Can you please replicate the issue in my stackblitz? hit fork, then do the edits and share it.

Comment: I have created new question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/56289748/1312610 this is my actual problem now

Answer (score 2):

Click event will be called every time, but it can be checked through index, whether it matches the expected index or not?

```html
<ul>
    <li class="list" *ngFor="let ver of versions; let i = index" (click)="versionView(i)">{{ver.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

And index can be checked on *.ts code as below:

```js
function versionView(i) {
    if (i == NTH_VALUE) {
         
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul>
    <li class="list" *ngFor="let ver of versions; let i = index" (click)="versionView()">{{ver.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

You can add `let i = index` in order to refer the nth element, and use it as you prefer. You can pass it as a parameter in your `versionView()` function and use it there.

```
function versionView(i) {
    if (i !== NTH_VALUE) {
        return 
    }
    // Execute your function here
}
```

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: If your problem is to run some code of n-th element of version, you won't probably need to change anything in your template, you can simply add a `this.versionView(versions[i])` wherever you need it in your JS/TS component file. Probably you can even use an easier syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You are really close. Modify your code like so:

```
<ul>
  <li class="list" *ngFor="let ver of versions" (click)="versionView(ver)">{{ver.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

In your corresponding component you just need to add:

```
versionView(ver: any) {
  // Do something with the ver object
}
```

Comment: When do you wish to call this function? You could for example call it in ngAfterViewInit: `ngAfterViewInit() { this.versionView(this.versions[n]); }` . This would call the function after the view has been initialised.