# Trigger click on specific item under nested loop Angular ngFor

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, ngfor

How to target on the specif item under the nested loop

```
<ul #parents *ngFor="let parent of parents">
     <li #child *ngFor="let child of parents.childGroup"> {{child.name}} </li>
<ul>
```

**Ts File**

Asper my code my target is `parents[5].child[0]`  , but its working as child `parents[0].child[0]`

```
@ViewChildren('parents') parents : QueryList<ElementRef>
 @ViewChildren('child') child: QueryList<ElementRef>

this.parents.forEach((item, index) => {
if (index === 5 ) {
(this.child.find( (item , index) => index === 0 ).nativeElement as HTMLElement).click();
}


});
```

Each parent has own children, Here target calculated based on all child index

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set **dynamic id** in html element like this:

```
<ul #parents *ngFor="let parent of parents">
     <li #child *ngFor="let child of parents.childGroup;let i=index" id="{{'child'+ i }}">
          {{child.name}} 
    </li>
<ul>
```

and then click from typescript.

```
this.parents.forEach((item, index) => {
  if (index === 5 ) {
    document.getElementById("child" + index  ).click();
  }
});
```

Comment: Its alternate solution, I will look this if there is no solution in angular

Comment: There is chance IDs duplicate same name, id name child1, child2, ... same repetition in each group

Comment: Index will not be duplicate, it will increment from 0 to ...n  and if you have diffect groups, give group specific name in place of 'child'. Maybe something like `{{'child'+ parent.name + i }}`

Comment: Okay including parentIndex number also in ID name 'child01' ,'child02' etc

Comment: Yes.. that would do

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without `ViewChild()` refs.

You can add an click event listener on the child component and pass it parameters.

```
<li *ngFor="let child of parent.children" (click)="handleClick(parent, child)">
```

And then handle the click accordingly.

```
handleClick(parent, child){
  console.log(parent);
  if(this.parents[1] === parent && (parent.children.indexOf(child)) === 1 ){
    alert(`You clicked ${child} of parent ${parent.id}`)
  }
}
```

Here is a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wjrrua?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)